# Linking outer html page to the reverse_lazy() of signup page

Tags: python, html, django

I have written code to develop a social media clone site using django. In that, after signup, i have to move to homepage instead of login page. The homepage html code is present in another folder outside of this current folder. I am unable to access the url of the html page from this. The code is:

```
    from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from . import forms

class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
    template_name = "accounts/signup.html"
```

Instead of "login", the url should be "base". The path of "login.html" is: "project/accounts/templates/accounts/login.html". And the path of "base.html" is: "project/templates/project/base.html". Please suggest me a method to modify this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the according URL and view, so you can redirect to that view:

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'project/base.html'


# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import MyView
urlpatterns += url(r'^my_url/', MyView.as_view(), name='my_view')

# signup view
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from . import forms

class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("my_view")
    template_name = "accounts/signup.html"
```

You may need to adapt a couple things, but the key is, that you need a URL and a View so you can redirect them there, once they signed up.

Comment: I am getting the same error. "Reverse for 'my_view' not found. 'my_view' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Answer (score 0):

You should use it with your application name.

url:

```
path('email-listesi/kayit-silindi/', UnsubscriptionSuccessful.as_view(), name='unsubscription-successful'),
```

views:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('yourapplicationname:unsubscription-successful')
```